# How to style JavaFX 2 Fullscreen message?

Tags: javafx-2

Going to Fullscreen mode in JavaFX causes a giant message telling the user that he can leave this mode pressing `ESC`. Not only this takes the "desktopish" feeling off my application, it also looks ugly.

I guess this message is not ment to be suppressed, so my hope is that i can at least brand it. So, how can i style it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a requests to [Allow trusted apps to disable the fullscreen overlay warning and disable the "Exit on ESC" behavior](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15314) and [Touch Screen only - Press ESC to exit full-screen mode. does not apply.](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25018) Neither request has been implemented as of JavaFX 2.2.

There are no requests to allow the message to be styled that I could find.  You could [create one under the JavaFX Runtime project](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com), but I think it would be rejected due to potential security concerns.

Answer (score 18):

JavaFX 8 has a way to suppress this message:

```
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You can just completely disable the message with:

```
primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
```