# Change fullscreen message language

Tags: javafx, fullscreen

I have **two problems** with my javafx application if I **switch** to **fullscreen**.

1) My application is completly written in english, and a language apart from english should never be supported. The FULLSCREEN-Message is displayed in german (my OS language). Can I change the language of this message for all Plattforms, no matter what language the user has?

2) The font-size is a way too big, can I change it via CSS? What css class selects this text?

Here is a screenshot to visualize my problem(s).

[image: Screenshot of fullscreen message]

Thank you for reading =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the message can be styled or disabled in JavaFX 2.2, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569206/how-to-style-javafx-2-fullscreen-message).

For the language, use `Locale.setDefault(...)`, *if it does not interfere with other aspects of the application*. If the langauage you set is supported, it will work (works for me on Windows 7 - Java 7 - JavaFX 2.2).

And to nag a bit: If I set `Locale` to `GERMAN` it does indeed display outside the box, just like your picture >:(

Comment: Thank you, Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH), fixed the design and language problem.