# How to disable Press ESC to exit full screen-mode meassage in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am working on Javafx application,my question is When my application starts it shows one message **Press ESC to exit full screen-mode** and this is very annoying for me, I don't want to display this message,I went through the link shown here :
[How to style JavaFX 2 Fullscreen message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569206/how-to-style-javafx-2-fullscreen-message)

but it didn't worked for me.please help me to get out of this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of JavaFX 8.0, you can call

```
stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
```

to disable the message in a trusted application. Note that, according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreenExitHint-java.lang.String-) setting the hint to `null` will not disable it, but will revert to the system-default message.

Comment: Thanks for reply @James_D, but this stage.setFullScreenExitHint(""); didn't worked for me, I have tried like this

Comment: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            //stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
            stage.show();

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] in your question? It works fine for me (but I cannot get full screen to work at all in combination with `UNDECORATED`).

Comment: Hey Thanks @James_D,Now it works fine,actually it was my fault,I have put the code you mentioned above somewhere else,that's why was not working but now it works fine.Thank You again :)

Comment: Or you can use this `primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);`